# Brownie: replacement transaction underpriced

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, brownie

I have a stuck transaction in brownie, when I try to deploy another contract I have this error:

> ValueError: replacement transaction underpriced

my deployment code is like this:

```
dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
print(network.show_active())
print(dev.nonce)
race_contract = Race.deploy(
    {"from": dev},
    publish_source=get_publish_source(),
)
```

How can I increase nonce or something like that ?